# Did Matsya Avatar kill any demon besides Hayagriva and did Kurma kill any demon too?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, asuras, matsya, kurma

I came across this beautiful image of various avatars of Lord Vishnu and interestingly it shows both Matsya and Kurma killing one demon each.

[image]

Now we know Matsya is believed to have played a role in the killing of Hayagriva but that seems to be depicted in a lower panel where Vishnu has the Hayagriva form as well.

So my question is two fold: - **Is this some other demon being killed by Matsya? Also is there are any scriptural references of Kurma Avatar killing any demons?**

Comment: https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/24/8/

Comment: https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/24/9/

Comment: These two verses from Bhagavata indicate Matsya killed a demon named Hayagriva

Comment: Yes that I already mentioned in the question am looking for any other demons besides Hayagriva.

Comment: [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lalitopakhyana-lalita-mahatmya/d/doc362967.html) of Lalitopakhyana mentiones that Devi turned away the demons who stoles Vedas by her nail. It is implied Matsya.